# How to show that $Bil(U,V,W) \simeq Hom(U \otimes V, W)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, tensor-products, tensors

> Let $U,V,W$ be vectorspcaes. Show that $Bil(U,V,W) \simeq Hom(U \otimes V, W)$ via the isomorphism $F$ given by:
>
> $$F(\varphi)(u \otimes v) = \varphi(u,v)$$
> for all $\varphi \in Bil(U,V,W)$, $u \in U$ and $v \in V$.

What U do not understand here is why $F$ is linear. I understand that to prove this we need to start with some $a,b \in U \otimes V$, with $a = u \otimes v$ and $b = u^\prime \otimes v^\prime$, and a scalar $\lambda$ and show that $F(\varphi)(\lambda a+b) = \lambda F(a) +F(b)$. However, when I try to prove this I get stuck quickly:

$$F(\varphi)(\lambda a+b) = F(\varphi)(\lambda(u \otimes v)+(u^\prime \otimes v^\prime)).$$

I do not see how to continue from here, could you please give me a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bil}{\operatorname{Bil}}\newcommand{\hom}{\operatorname{Hom}}$*The linearity of $F$ and the linearity of $F(\varphi)$ are different statements.*

This is not a full answer, just a detailed response to your first query and some hints for how to complete the proof. I try to point out exactly what you *do* need to show, in case it is unclear.

Since the tensor product is uniquely defined by the property you state, we need to know how *you* are defining it. I will then assume the definition involving tensor relations.

Moreover, notice the definition of $F$ is incomplete. You are supposed to infer $F(\varphi)$ is linearly extended! Knowing the value on some tensor $u\otimes v$ is not sufficient, since what is $F(\varphi)(u\otimes v+u'\otimes v')$? So far, this is undefined. So we implicitly say, let $F(\varphi)$ be the linear map defined by the action on the tensor "basis", $u\otimes v\mapsto\varphi(u,v)$. Specifically, any element of $U\otimes V$ can be written as a formal linear combination of pure tensors: I define $F(\varphi)(\sum\lambda_i(u_i\otimes v_i))$ to be $\sum\lambda_iF(\varphi)(u_i\otimes v_i)$. That is what is meant by linear extension, and this and similar ideas are used very often in algebra *implicitly*, so you need to get used to it and recognise it.

But we do need to check this is *well-defined*, for we have certain tensor relations:

> $$u\otimes v+u'\otimes v=(u+u')\otimes v,\,u\otimes v+u\otimes v'=u\otimes(v+v')\\\lambda(u\otimes v)=(\lambda u\otimes v)=u\otimes(\lambda v)$$

That can morph a linear combination of tensor elements into a single one. So I want to be sure that $F(\varphi)$ makes sense when defined as a linear extension by comparing its value using the two definitions, which a priori might be different. Let's look at the first relation, I leave the treatment of the other two to you: $$F(\varphi)(u\otimes v+u'\otimes v):=F(\varphi)(u\otimes v)+F(\varphi)(u'\otimes v)=\varphi(u,v)+\varphi(u',v)$$**Is that consistent**? Yes: $$\varphi(u,v)+\varphi(u',v)=F(\varphi)(u\otimes v+u'\otimes v)=F(\varphi)((u+u')\otimes v):=\varphi(u+u',v)$$Is true because $\varphi$ is linear in the first variable: the two definitions are consistent.

*$U\otimes V$ is actually constructed with these relations precisely so that the isomorphism $\hom(U\otimes V,W)\cong\bil(U,V;W)$ holds. This hints how to find $F^{-1}$ and check it is well-defined.*

So, for any $\varphi\in\bil(U,V;W)$, $F(\varphi)\in\hom(U\otimes V,W)$ is a well-defined linear map. It is now up to you to demonstate:

- $F$ is a linear map, i.e. $F(\lambda\varphi+\lambda'\varphi')=\lambda F(\varphi)+\lambda' F(\varphi')$
- $F$ is a bijection

Then you can claim: $$\bil(U,V;W)\cong\hom(U\otimes V,W)$$